# Finding help for setting up QGIS Web Client in Windows 7

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

Is there any procedure or installation guide of QGIS Web Client for Windows 7 OS? Because I'm really having a hard time setting up the Web Client in Win7 and I don't know any Linux-based commands that's featured in https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client.

My QGIS Server is running well and I'm using QGIS 1.8.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/